# Applaying TurnstileFeatherEffect to Panorama Items slide

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control, windows-phone-toolkit

I'm a bit curious. I am new to windows phone development, and currently trying to find adequate way to animate my application. 
I'm using **TurnstileFeatherEffect** from **WindowsPhoneToolkit** for animating page transition.

Now I wonder can I use it for animating Panorama items sliding, and how?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the part of interest inside the TurnstileFeatherEffect's source code
[here](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/Effects/TurnstileFeatherEffect.cs)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Default list of types that cannot be feathered.
    /// </summary>
    private static IList<Type> _nonPermittedTypes = new List<Type>() 
        { 
            typeof(PhoneApplicationFrame), 
            typeof(PhoneApplicationPage), 
            typeof(PivotItem),
            typeof(Panorama),
            typeof(PanoramaItem)
        };
```